# How to split one column into multiple columns, based on similar values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

In this Dataframe (a piece of a much larger dataframe), I'd like to separate blue from red so they are on two different columns. (Each person only has two colors.)

```
        Person        Buckets_used
0       Jerry_blue    180 
1       Jerry_red     20
2       Tomba_blue    30
3       Tomba_red     600
```

**I would like to create the dataframe below but I'm not sure how.** Should regular expressions be used here or is there a more efficient way?

```
        Person        Buckets_used   Person      Buckets_used
0       Jerry_blue    180            Jerry_red   20      
1       Tomba_blue    30             Tomba_red  600
```

When I try to do the following suggested solution by @Wen:

```
df=df.set_index('Key').groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x : np.concatenate(x.values.tolist())).apply(pd.Series)
```

I get some values in incorrect columns.

```
        Person        Buckets_used   Person      Buckets_used
0       Jerry_blue    180            Jerry_red   20      
1       Tomba_red     600            Tomba_blue  30
```

**Is there a way to fix that so all the reds are under one column and the blue under another?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need new para Key by using `str.split`

```
df['Key']=df.Person.str.split('_',expand=True)[0]
df
Out[37]: 
       Person  Buckets_used    Key
0  Jerry_blue           180  Jerry
1   Jerry_red            20  Jerry
2  Tomba_blue            30  Tomba
3   Tomba_red           600  Tomba
```

Then we `groupby`

```
df=df.set_index('Key').groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x : np.concatenate(x.values.tolist())).apply(pd.Series)
df
Out[47]: 
                0    1          2    3
Key                                   
Jerry  Jerry_blue  180  Jerry_red   20
Tomba  Tomba_blue   30  Tomba_red  600
```

Then we make the column name

```
df.columns=['Person','Buckets_used']*int(df.shape[1]/2)
df
Out[53]: 
           Person Buckets_used     Person Buckets_used
Key                                                   
Jerry  Jerry_blue          180  Jerry_red           20
Tomba  Tomba_blue           30  Tomba_red          600
```

Updated

```
df['Key']=df.Person.str.split('_',expand=True)[1]

df['Key1']=df.groupby('Key').cumcount()

df.set_index(['Key1','Key']).unstack()
Out[400]: 
          Person            Buckets_used     
Key         blue        red         blue  red
Key1                                         
0     Jerry_blue  Jerry_red          180   20
1     Tomba_blue  Tomba_red           30  600
```

Comment: we can use `df.shape[1]//2` instead of `int(df.shape[1]/2)`

Comment: I came up with this. But you can probably do it without a key. `v = df.groupby(df.Person.str.split('_').str[0]).apply(pd.Series.tolist)` and then `pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(v.tolist(), axis=1))`

Comment: Then just set the columns.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yeah that is succinct :-)

Comment: Thank you cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, MaxU and @Wen. I appreciate it. It definitely did the job.

Comment: @AdamSchroeder yw ~ :-)

Comment: Is there a way to fix the suggested solution so all the reds are under one column and the blue under another? @Wen

Comment: @AdamSchroeder you mean cold's solution ?

Comment: Yes @Wen. his solution did not work. it gave me an error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'asobject'. Your solution was almost flawless. The only problem is that a few person_red values and person_blue values were mixed under the same column. I can't figure out why that is...

Comment: @AdamSchroeder My method and cold's method are required the original df is well sorted , if not that will create the problem

Comment: @AdamSchroeder I have updated another solution , try that one

Comment: aha. I missed that. Thank you, @Wen. Now that it was sorted, it works. Have a good week.

Comment: @AdamSchroeder yw~ :-)